# Android TestCase subclasses

Tags: android, testing, junit

I am learning how to use the Android version of JUnit and I am confused about all the different subclasses of `TestCase`. In particular, how do I decide when to extend `ActivityUnitTestCase`, `ActivityTestCase`, `InstrumentationTestCase` or `AndroidTestCase` rather than `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`? Perhaps part of my confusion is that I am new to testing in general and I am unclear about the differences between the different kinds of tests (e.g. unit, functional, integration, etc.). I think some examples might help clear up some of this confusion for me.